# Manual file caching in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, caching, browser, cross-browser

I have an HTML based project that works with media from other websites, which embeds images / songs / videos using their direct links. The system works perfectly so far, but I wish to make a change: As a lot of assets are accessed repeatedly by viewers, it would seem more optimal to cache them in a controlled way, so whenever certain media pops up you don't need to fetch it from the origin server each time. I never did this before so I don't know if and how it can be done.

To use an oversimplification: I have an embedded photo called "image.png" inside an image element, which will show up whenever I open the site. Currently it's simply defined as:

```
<img scr="https://foo.bar/image.png">
```

Works perfectly! However I want to make sure that when my site is accessed, you don't need to fetch that image from foo.bar each time: You will keep it in a local directory after downloading it once, from which the script can fetch and work with the file independently. For Firefox for instance, this subdirectory would be inside your `~/.mozilla/firefox/my_profile` directory. Ideally it can be defined using a fixed name, so no matter which URL the website is opened from it uses the same cache path instead of each mirror of the project generating its own.

First, my script must tell the browser to download `https://foo.bar/image.png` and store it into this cache subdirectory. After that, it would need to generate a link to embed it directly from that subdirectory, so the URL I use would now be something of the following form:

```
<img scr="file://path_to_cache/image.png">
```

How do I do those two things, in a way that's compatible across popular web browsers? As a bonus, it would be useful to know if I can limit the size of this cache directory, so once it reaches say 100 MB the oldest items will be removed to stay under that size.

Comment: You don't need to implement such a caching engine yourself. Browsers have asset caching implemented in themselves. here is a link for you to look into https://medium.com/@codebyamir/a-web-developers-guide-to-browser-caching-cc41f3b73e7c

Comment: "Works perfectly! " Well it would not work perfectly since it is `src`

Comment: So you want to reinvent browser caching? So you going to write an extension?

Comment: Okay; I probably shouldn't be looking to reinvent browser caching. I was thinking of using this system to do more complex things, like making a local copy of the site able to work offline... I guess browser caching could do this as well though? Perhaps what I need is the ability to tell the browser for how long to cache an image, as by default it seems to drop assets too quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You could alternately add caching to your server's .htaccess file.
This site explains how: https://www.siteground.com/kb/leverage-browser-caching/
However this does not cache the image on the user's machine, it is cached on the server for quicker response.

You could use service workers to cache images on the user's machine.
https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/lab-caching-files-with-service-worker

Hope this helps.

Comment: The site is meant to be stored in various locations, like Github Pages or IPFS... server specific settings can't be made part of its functionality. There doesn't seem to be any direct solution to control browser caching of an image from JS.